# strandSort homework, iterator issues?

Tags: java

This is part of a homework problem of mine.

We were given the following pseudocode for strandsort:

```
    define strandSort( L )
      result = []
      while len(L) > 0
        inorder = []
        remove first element of L, add it to inorder
        for each item i in L:
          if i >= last item in inorder
            remove i from L, add it to inorder
        result = merge(inorder,result)
      return result
```

I implemented the code in the program as follows:

```
public List<Integer> strandSort(List<Integer> nums) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(nums.size() > 0){
        List<Integer> inorder = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int toAdd = nums.remove(0);
        inorder.add(toAdd);
        for(Integer i : nums){
            if (i >= inorder.get(0) ){
                toAdd = nums.remove((int)i);
                inorder.add(toAdd);
            }
        }
        result = merge(inorder, result);
    }
    return result;
```

However, I run into an out of bounds error on the " for(Integer i : nums) " line. I believe I realize why this is happening. I am trying to iterate through the list, while at the same time removing elements from it.

What I'm not sure about is how to fix it. If I implemented the pseudocode correctly, I don't believe it would run into errors like this. Therefore, I'm thinking I didn't implement it correctly.

If I have, what's the best way to rework the strandSort code without destroying the input list?

(I apologize for double posting, I accidentally submitted the question before I finished explaining!)

Comment: Are you sure the exception is not in the `nums.remove((int)i)` line?  And does it still happen if you don't put the `(int)` cast?  The reason that I ask is that there are two versions of the `remove` method - one where you pass the actual thing you want to remove, and another where you pass an `int` specifying what position in the list the thing to be removed is in.  Obviously, you want the former; but by specifying that the argument is an `int`, you may be getting the wrong version of the `remove` method.

Comment: Same thing I said in your duplicate post--please don't do that, edit your question instead. You cannot get that exception in a `for` loop, it's in your `remove`, for the reason I stated earlier.

Comment: The compile tells me it's the for loop line, but I realize that when I remove an element from the list that's where the problem really starts.
The program will not compile if I remove the int cast, because remove() then returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toAdd = nums.remove((int)i);` is your culprit.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

> E  remove(int index)
>   Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation).
>
> boolean    remove(Object o)
>   Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present (optional operation).

It's confusing because you're casting an `Integer` to an `int`, causing the first version of `remove()` to be called.  This causes your code to remove the element *at* `i` instead of `i` itself.  Try getting rid of the explicit `(int)` cast.

Comment: *first version of `remove()` to be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i >= inorder.get(0) ){
```

is not the same as

```
if i >= last item in inorder
```

In the first case you are getting the first one, not the last one.